# How do I unlock "Professor B's Return"?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I've already done the prerequisite mission involving getting a car at whatnot and Professor B's Return isn't appearing.

Comment: To clarify, you've done the Mystery Man normal mission, or some other mission? If so, you should talk to Professor B's assistant in the industrial district.

Comment: I've done Mystery Man, but his assistant doesn't have a red "?" above his head.